# How to override CSS style for a specific <td> element if its parent has a specific class

Tags: html, css

```
.webgrid-table td, th {
    border: 1px solid #98bf21;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px;
}
```

the above style is getting applied for all td but i want do not want to apply the above style for a td which is in tr having class called `webgrid-footer`

so i tried to exclude the td inside a tr having class `webgrid-footer` this way

```
.webgrid-footer td {
     padding: 0px,0px,0px;
}
```

but it is not working. here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/pta7Ln59/

here is image like what i want
[image]

just see the pager there is a space which i want to trim out. so suggest me what to change in css. thanks

Comment: see this tr <tr class="webgrid-footer">

Comment: `padding: 0;` instead of `padding: 0px,0px,0px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mou again! You only got the Syntax of the padding wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/pta7Ln59/2/

```
.webgrid-footer td {
     padding: 0;
}
```

The commas are not OK: `padding: 0px,0px,0px;` (`padding: 0px 0px 0px;` would be ok)

---

To remove the remaining spaces add this rule: https://jsfiddle.net/pta7Ln59/3/

```
.webgrid-footer .paginate.pag5 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

(class `.paginate.pag5` had a margin, so you have to remove it)

Comment: yes worked but space is coming at bottom. what to fix.

Comment: I use that little trick (background color): `.webgrid-footer td {padding: 0px;background:red;}` to find out more about spaces. As you can see there is no padding anymore. It is because of the inner Element, let me check I will come back with an answer

Comment: @Mou OK, I added the code. Is this what you need now? https://jsfiddle.net/pta7Ln59/3/

Comment: @Mou the extra space is due to the margin on the `.paginate` class. You need to clear out the margin on that element.

Comment: Well someone downvoted this answer, and I wanted to know why

Comment: i gave you the vote. how do u see who gave u down vote.....is it possible in this forum?

Comment: You can see it when clicking on the vote number, but you need a certain amount of reputation first. It will show you how many up- and down-votes any answer has, but you can't see who voted.

Comment: @Mou: Anyway, glad to help you again Mou, cheers. It's looking good!

Comment: @CodeiSir I don't see any downvotes on your answer. They must have taken it back.

Comment: @TimBanks yes it was removed

Answer (score 4):

Your CSS is invalid since you have commas in between the pixel values. Change your CSS to not use commas

```
.webgrid-footer td {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) to negate all `tr` elements that have the class `.webgrid-footer`. From there, you can select the descendant `td`/`th` elements:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/h4ovm3gc/)

```
tr:not(.webgrid-footer) td,
tr:not(.webgrid-footer) th {
  border: 1px solid #98BF21;
  padding: 3px 7px 2px;
}
```

Comment: not selector do not work in old browser and also in IE.

Comment: @Mou It works in IE9. Also, if you want to remove the space around the element, you can add `.paginate { margin: 0; }` - https://jsfiddle.net/m2zfsq7g/

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific

try

```
tr.webgrid-footer td { padding: 0; }
```

or

```
.webgrid-table .webgrid-footer td { padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

- your rule isn't more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than  `.webgrid-table td, th`
- you don't have the right syntax (there's no comma)

Here's a fixed one:

```
.webgrid-table .webgrid-footer td {
     padding: 0 0 0;
}
```

Side notes:

- a major good practice is to be careful about ensuring a big enough specificity of your rules even when it doesn't, at first, *seem* to matter, or you'll have random bugs when maintaining your code and you'll end up putting `!important` in your code (which is a definite red flag)
- you probably don't want `.webgrid-table td, th` which targets *all* `th` elements but `.webgrid-table td, .webgrid-table th`.
- I suppose you probably want also `margin:0` on your `ul` element.

Comment: "your rule isn't more specific than" is wrong (you don't need it to be), it's only the commas. You should check your answer before claiming stuff

Comment: @CodeiSir And maybe you should check your answer for typos and spelling mistakes!

Comment: @JoshCrozier Sorry I am dyslexic. But thanks I corrected one

Comment: @CodeiSir Please have a look at the link I give

Comment: @DenysSéguret I know what you are saying, but it does not apply to this problem

Comment: *Your rule isn't more specific than* - That is not wrong at all. They have the same specificity because both `.webgrid-table td` and `.webgrid-footer td` have one class selector, one type selector and so their specificity is indeed same. But whether that makes a difference or not is a different thing.

Comment: @Harry I was saying it's wrong beacause it doesn't need to be more specific. Claiming this is a problem is wrong.

Comment: @CodeiSir: I agree with that point but I think your original comment just said it was wrong (and didn't say why). Or maybe I read it wrong. Anyway lets leave it there.

Comment: @Harry you are right, I edited the comment to be clear about what I intended to say